# Value not defined in first render but defined in next render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I recently started using `useEffect` hook, and I'm facing some issues. This is a simple `App` component that renders an input field and submit button. On hitting submit `selectItem` is called which in turn calls an async function `getNames()`. `getNames` function checks if there is an existing entry, if so it returns, otherwise it calls 3rd party API `getNewNames()` to get newNames. I tried setting the state with this `newNames` field, but it seems like it is undefined in first render. But after the first render it is defined. How do I make sure that I have `newNames` field, so that it doesn't return undefined in any renders?

```
const App = () => {

  const [namesArr, setNamesArr] = useState([])
  const [name, setName] = useState('')

  useEffect (()=> {
    console.log('Inside use Effect')
  }, [namesArr])



  const changeInput = (val) => {
    setName(val)
  }


  const selectItem = async() => {
    const returnedVal = await getNames()
    // ReturnVal is empty in first render, but filled in second render. 
    /
  }

  const getNames = async() =>{
    const existingNames = namesArr.find((name)=> name === name)
    if(existingNames){
      return 'We have an entry'
    }
    else{
      console.log(`Names are not reloaded properly, need to re-render`)
      const newNames = await getNewNames() // this is 
      setName((oldNames)=> [...oldNames, newNames])
      return namesArr
    }
  }


  return <div>
    <input value={name} onChange={(e)=> changeInput(e.target.value)}></input>
    <button onClick={()=> selectItem()}></button>
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Instead of `return namesArr` couldn't you just `return [newNames]` in the getNames function ?

Comment: That would still return empty array

Comment: It would return an array with whatever this call outputs `await getNewNames()`.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is related to the setName method. In the line after setName console.log(namesArr) will be undefined. So how can we fix this?

```
const getNames = async() =>{
    const existingNames = namesArr.find((name)=> name === name)
    if(existingNames){
      return 'We have an entry'
    }
    else{
      const newNames = await getNewNames();

      // We created our new list outside
      // If x is a list, prepend an ellipsis ...newNames
      const newList = [...namesArr, newNames];

      // setName string is a state. Incorrect state updating.
      // setNamesArr instead of setName
      setNamesArr(newList)

      return newList;
    }
  }
```

Now there are two possibilities here.
**returnedVal === array** or **returnedVal === 'We have an entry'**

```
const selectItem = async() => {
    const returnedVal = await getNames();
    console.log(returnedVal); // array or string.
}
```

Comment: The approach I went is to define ```useEffect``` and added a dependency of ```newList``` to it. Whenever I have ```newList``` in ```useEffect``` I use it to do other work